# Missing Database Table cakephp even table is there

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.3, cakephp-model

I have a database where all tables are prefixed by "bs" . I baked a model from bs_states table and it's generate the following code.

```
<?php
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
/**
 * State Model
 *
 * @property country $Country
 * @property Seller $Seller
 */
class State extends AppModel {

/**
 * Use table
 *
 * @var mixed False or table name
 */
    public $useTable = '_states';

/**
 * Primary key field
 *
 * @var string
 */
    public $primaryKey = 'state_id';

/**
 * Display field
 *
 * @var string
 */
    public $displayField = 'state_iso';


    //The Associations below have been created with all possible keys, those that are not needed can be removed

/**
 * belongsTo associations
 *
 * @var array
 */
    public $belongsTo = array(
        'Country' => array(
            'className' => 'country',
            'foreignKey' => 'country_iso',
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => ''
        )
    );

/**
 * hasMany associations
 *
 * @var array
 */
    public $hasMany = array(
        'Seller' => array(
            'className' => 'Seller',
            'foreignKey' => 'state_id',
            'dependent' => false,
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => '',
            'limit' => '',
            'offset' => '',
            'exclusive' => '',
            'finderQuery' => '',
            'counterQuery' => ''
        )
    );

}
```

This code is working fine in local system but when I upload it to the prodution server it showing following message.

> Missing Database Table
>   Error: Table bsstates for model State was not found in datasource default.

Initially I thought it's a cache issue so I've done the following:

- I have cleared the tmp/cache directory
- I changed the debug mode `Configure::write('debug', 0);` to `Configure::write('debug', 2);`

But no luck. I am still facing the same problem. My database connection on production server is good because other model are working fine.

Comment: Are you sure? Your code says it should have an underscore between the `bs` and `states`: `public $useTable = '_states';`

Comment: Paste your db file as well (obviously don't include username/pass w/ it though)

Comment: What is the table name in the database?

Comment: @Andy Yes it is working fine in my local system.

Comment: @enigmasck Here is my table structure.

`
--
-- Table structure for table `bs_states`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `bs_states` (
  `state_id` bigint(255) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `country_iso` varchar(50) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `state` varchar(200) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `state_iso` varchar(50) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `state_order` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `active` tinyint(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`state_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_general_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=4067 ;

`

Comment: @Basant It seems like your convention is off. See my answer below. You need to change the model name to be `BsStates`, which the cakephp magic will map to bs_states in the db.

Comment: instead of  public $useTable = '_states';
you can write  public $useTable = 'states';
and add that underscore(_) in prefix in database configuration in database.php as 'bs_'.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the $useTable property and use

```
public $tablePrefix = 'bs_';
```

Comment: what message did you get?

Comment: Still same message. Missing Database Table Error: Table bsstates for model State was not found in datasource default.

Comment: well, if that's the message then use 'bs' and not 'bs_'

Answer (score 0):

First place to look when you're in a production environment is the logs. They also give more information than the debug print out. Navigate to here:

`\app\tmp\logs`

This error is usually accompanied with insufficient privileges on the table. Make sure the db role for Cake has privileges on that table.

Since you say it works fine locally it makes me think it's a DB privilege issue, but also the CakePHP convention seems to be off.

The Model class name should be:

`BsStates`

and the class variable `$useTable` should be:

`public $useTable = 'bs_states';`

Answer (score 0):

instead of writing `public $useTable = '_states';` 
you can write and `public $useTable = 'states';` 
add that underscore() 
prefix in database configuration in database.php as 'bs_'.

or add `public $tablePrefix = 'bs_';` in this file.